# Can someone help me with memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, plist, automatic-ref-counting, nsdictionary

**EDIT: I USE ARC IN PROJECT**

I load annotations from plist like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadPList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

...

```
- (void) loadPList
{

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; // memory leak here

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        NSMutableArray * annotationsToRemove = [ mapView.annotations mutableCopy ] ;
        [ annotationsToRemove removeObject:mapView.userLocation ] ;
        [ mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove ] ;



        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blackKey"])
        {

            NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:@"Black"];

            for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) {

                NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

                double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
                double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

                MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
                theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

                myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
                myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
                myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];

                [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
                [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];

            }

        }   


    });


}
```

All loads fine, but Memory leak tool shows me an leak.

[image: leak screenshot]

Comment: The only way that could leak is if there's no autorelease pool active.  Check your console for "just leaking" messages.

Comment: I think it's leaks because i run this code as a new thread [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadPList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

Comment: If you're running it in its own thread you need to add an autorelease pool.

Comment: (I assumed you were using ARC since you'd specified the "automatic-ref-counting" tag.)

Comment: Ok.. where I need to put @autoreleasepool { ... } ?

Comment: Since loadPlist appears to be at the "bottom" of your stack, you need to put it there.  Basically bracket the body of your method with the autoreleasepool range.

Comment: (Understand that at the boundary of the autorelease range all autoreleased objects that were allocated within it (and not otherwise retained) will go "poof".)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `@autoreleasepool` at the start of your method - with that `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` call outside of it, you're creating an autoreleased object without a pool, so it'll leak. [Per the threading programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW17):

> If your application uses the managed memory model, creating an
>   autorelease pool should be the first thing you do in your thread entry
>   routine. Similarly, destroying this autorelease pool should be the
>   last thing you do in your thread.

Also, can I ask why you to use `NSThread` for loading the plist rather than a `dispatch_async()`using a global queue? I don't often see `dispatch_async()` nested inside a thread detachment, so just curious.

**EDIT:**

To fix your memory leak, without disturbing your thread / GCD hybrid, call your method like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadPList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

And implement it like this:

```
- (void) loadPList
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; // memory leak here

        NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSMutableArray * annotationsToRemove = [ mapView.annotations mutableCopy ] ;
            [ annotationsToRemove removeObject:mapView.userLocation ] ;
            [ mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove ] ;

            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blackKey"])
            {
                NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:@"Black"];

                for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) 
                {
                    NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

                    double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
                    double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

                    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
                    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

                    myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
                    myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                    myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
                    myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];

                    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
                    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];
                }
            }   
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried like this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{
                       
                       [self loadPList];
                       
                   });
but getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654522/nsarraym-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated

Comment: Well in that case you were executing the entirety of your method in the background, including the non-thread-safe parts. You have a different implementation of `loadPlist` in this question than in that one - you have the right idea now with sending the non-thread-safe parts back to the main queue. Anyways what happens if you try `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ [self loadPList]; });` now with your new implementation of `loadPlist`?

Comment: I get signal SIGABRT and error: Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x21c35500> was mutated while being enumerated. Here: [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

Comment: Did moving the `@autorelease` fix your memory leak? Also, you now have two different versions of the code in two different questions helping you fix problems in parallel. Which one is the correct version? Because in this question right now you have the `@autorelease` in the wrong place, but are correctly sending UI code back to the main thread. In the other question, you put the autorelease in the right place, but don't send the UI code back to the main thread - which is probably the cause of your crash.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen I updated my answer to explicit about what I was talking about. I'll go answer your other question which is what I think should probably be done to resolve both of your issues in the most correct way.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen I'm stumped at the moment. Can you run the static analyzer and see what it says?

Comment: Carl, it's leaking without dispatch_async at line: NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you need an autorelease pool. To quote from the documentation for [`detachNewThreadSelector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000311-CHDEBGEC), "the method `aSelector` is responsible for setting up an autorelease pool for the newly detached thread and freeing that pool before it exits."

Personally, I'd probably just invoke `loadPlist` via GCD rather than `detachNewThreadSelector`, and then you don't need to worry about an autorelease pool:

```
dispatch_async(get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self loadPlist];
});
```

Comment: app crashes with error: __NSArrayM was mutated while being enumerated

Comment: At what point in the code did this occur? If it's not showing you the offending line, try adding an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) and maybe that can help you identify it. Or set some manual breakpoints and slowly narrow down the problem. But the bug is not leaping out at me as a glance at your above code.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // Never released
NSMutableArray * annotationsToRemove = [ mapView.annotations mutableCopy ] ; // Never released
MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init]; // Never released
```

Your method should look like this:

```
- (void) loadPList {
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; // memory leak here
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSMutableArray * annotationsToRemove = [[mapView.annotations mutableCopy] autorelease];
        [annotationsToRemove removeObject:mapView.userLocation] ;
        [mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove] ;
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blackKey"])
        {

            NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:@"Black"];

            for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) {

                NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

                double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
                double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

                MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[[MyAnnotation alloc] init] autorelease];
                CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
                theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

                myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);
                myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
                myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];

                [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
                [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];

            }
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry then. I never used ARC, I'm using the classic style :) init / copy / create - release

Comment: @Vlad, while I respect your decision to remain in MRC, this is still not the answer to his question.  -1 unfortunately.