# NSArrayM was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: iphone, xcode, sigabrt, dispatch, mutated

App crashes with error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x21481c10> was mutated while being enumerated.'`

**This happen only if I move over mapview when my annotations is loading. If I doesn't touch map, no error occurred.**

```
- (void) startloading
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{

                       [self loadPList];

                   });
}
```

my code is:

```
- (void) loadPList
{

@autoreleasepool {

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



            NSMutableArray * annotationsToRemove = [ mapView.annotations mutableCopy ] ;
            [ annotationsToRemove removeObject:mapView.userLocation ] ;
            [ mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove ] ;


        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blackKey"])
        {

            NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:@"Black"];

            for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) {

                NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

                double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
                double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

                MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
                theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

                myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
                myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
                myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];

                [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation]; // SIGNAL SIGABRT
                [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];


            }

        }   



        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blueyellowKey"])
        {

            NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:@"BlueYellow"];

            for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) {

                NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

                double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
                double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

                MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
                theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

                myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
                myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
                myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];

                [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
                [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];              

            }

        }   



   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should change your `loadPlist` method to this, and then just call `[self loadPlist]` to invoke it:

```
- (void) loadPList
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

        //ALL THIS CODE FROM HERE ON OUT IS NOT THREAD SAFE! YOU ARE ACCESSING THE UI AND MUST PERFORM IT ON THE MAIN THREAD!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSMutableArray * annotationsToRemove = [ mapView.annotations mutableCopy ] ;
            [ annotationsToRemove removeObject:mapView.userLocation ] ;
            [ mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove ] ;


            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blackKey"])
            {
                NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:@"Black"];
                for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) {
                    NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

                    double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
                    double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

                    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
                    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

                    myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
                    myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                    myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
                    myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];

                    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation]; // SIGNAL SIGABRT
                    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];
                }
            }   

            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blueyellowKey"])
            {
                NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:@"BlueYellow"];

                for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) 
                {
                    NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

                    double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
                    double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

                    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
                    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

                    myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
                    myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
                    myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
                    myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];

                    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
                    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];              
                }
            }   
        }
    });
 }
```

This performs the IO work of reading in the annotations in the background, and then passes off the UI work back to the main thread. Hope this helps!

Comment: @PavelKaljunen which object is leaking?

Comment: NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: if I remove dispatch_async, then it doesn't leak

Comment: The inner or outer one? Also with your two questions with different code I'm unsure what exactly you're doing. Why don't you resolve this question, and update your memory leak question with your current code - your implementation of loadPlist and the place where you call it, along with any instruments results indicating the leak. That will really help me help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I updated this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653016/memory-leak-on-new-thread-using-arc